# how to render single vue instance into different dom locations

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Suppose you have to render paginated data.

A paginator component should appear **above and below** the data table rendering exactly the same output.

The most basic approach would be declaring the paginator component twice - one above the data and one below. But the resulting vnodes (and even the dom fragment) of the paginator component instances will be equal. Both paginator instances would compute (also twice !) completely equal vnode and dom fragments.

I would like to avoid duplicated vnodes/dom node rendering and computation time. Basically compute everything once and duplicating the resulting nodes would be the ideal goal.

My current known options:

1. Hacking something like a single Vue pagination component and cloning its resulting DOM output to somewhere else sounds like a bad idea because of potential Vuiejs $ref and dom/vuejs event handling issues. *So this is actually no option.*
2. What about cloning the vnode of the first pagination component instance and reuse it for the second instance ? Is that the way to go ?

What is the best option ?

Are there any better approaches to match my expectations ?

Comment: Why not use `slot` inside the paginator component. You'll juste have to duplicate your display divs before and after the slot

Comment: The best solution is to handle pagination in the parent component. And use child components only for displaying data.

Comment: That approach does'nt prevent duplicated computation of the paginator vnodes. How about creating a functional component (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components) which returns the cloned vnodes of the first paginator in its render() method ?

Comment: What about a component designed like this: `<VuePaginator template='urltemplate' pages=20 current=5></VuePaginator>` without the dependency between?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't read the bottom list :)